# OnEntry method not working, when using postsharp for AOP

Tags: c#, .net, aop, fluentvalidation, postsharp

Hi I am trying to use postsharp aspect for validation. `FluentValidationAspect` does not working for OnEntry method. **(postsharp v6.9.6)**

**FluentValidationAspect**

```
[Serializable]
public class FluentValidationAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    private Type _validatorType;
    public FluentValidationAspect(Type validatorType)
    {
        _validatorType = validatorType;
    }
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        var validator = (IValidator)Activator.CreateInstance(_validatorType);

        var entityType = _validatorType.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var entities = args.Arguments.Where(o => o.GetType() == entityType);

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            ValidatorTool.FluentValidate(validator, entity);
        }
    }
}
```

It does not go inside the OnEntry method in any way.

**ProductManager**

```
    [FluentValidationAspect(typeof(ProductValidator))]
    public Product Add(Product product)
    {
        return _productDal.Add(product);
    }
```

**Test**

```
[TestClass]
public class ProductManagerTests
{
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ValidationException))]
    [TestMethod]
    public void Product_Validation_Check()
    {
        Mock<IProductDal> mock = new Mock<IProductDal>();
        ProductManager productManager = new ProductManager(mock.Object);

        productManager.Add(new Product());
    }
}
```

**ILSpy**
[image]

Comment: Do you have the `PostSharp` NuGet package installed in your project? This looks like you have just the `PostSharp.Redist` package installed.

Comment: Yes, I use these aspects in two class library. I had installed the postsharp package in only one of them. Now when I installed the in other one, the problem was solved. Actually, I didn't think that there would be a problem because it references the other when you install it on one. Thank you.

Comment: Great. I'm happy that this has helped. I've rewritten my suggestion to an answer. May I ask you to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each project in which PostSharp aspects are applied needs to have the `PostSharp` NuGet package installed.